# Httpsession management in springMVC

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, httpsession

I am new to spring MVC and started to make a sample application by doing what I learned. I am planning to implement Session management in spring MVC. I found [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/spring-mvc-session-tutorial.html) one helpful.

But I am not able to get it clearly. We add values to the session like

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
session.setAttribute("key", value);
session.setAttribute("key1",  value1);
```

and later on we fetch values based on the keys like

```
session.getAttrubute("key");
```

but in spring MVC, I could not see anything similar and it totally confuses me.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("thought")
public class SingleFieldController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/single-field")
    public ModelAndView singleFieldPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("single-field-page");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/remember")  
    public ModelAndView rememberThought(@RequestParam String thoughtParam) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("thought", thoughtParam);
        modelAndView.setViewName("single-field-page");
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

In the above code  `@SessionAttributes("thought")` is totally confusing me like what is this `thought` defined also I have no need to return a `ModelAndView` since I am using `backbone.marionette.js`

So how can I set values in a session and use them whenever required? I also have to convert the session object to my user defined object since, while returning the values to screen, I return only a List of UserDefined objects which are available in the session.

So please help me to understand it better. Maybe I am confused with the way I used jsp / servlet.

**UPDATE**

Below is the controller I have and provided comments

```
package com.hexgen.puppet;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import com.hexgen.puppet.CreatePuppet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@Controller
public class PuppetService {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/create")
    public @ResponseBody
    void createOrder(@RequestBody CreatePuppet request) {
        //logic to add/update values in session
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/list")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<Puppet> getGroups() {
        //logic to retrive objects from session and convert it as List and send it back

        return puppets;
    }


}
```

and convert the object if needed and go on

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*@SessionAttributes* doesn't fully replaces the traditional *HttpServlet* session management. Use it if two or more Controller methods need to communicate some data. But, using this we can only achieve communication within single controller class. You do not use to read and write from and to the session explicitly if you are using *@SessionAttributes*. Usage of *@SessionAttributes* is suggested only for short lived communications. If you need to store long term data in session, it is suggested to use *session.setAttribute* and *session.getAttribute* explicitly, instead of *@SessionAttributes*. For more information [check this out](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.web/3.1.0/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.java#SessionAttributes).

Answer (score 12):

You can handle session management in  springmvc like this. here is a controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String login(HttpSession session,String username,String password) throws Exception {
    Member member=userService.authenticateUser(username, password);
    if(member!=null) {
        session.setAttribute("MEMBER", member);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Invalid username or password");
    }
    return Utils.toJson("SUCCESS");
}
```

user will be passing username and password while Spring will automatically inject session attribute. we will authenticate this username and password 
 from db. For this we will be using some service method which will in turn call some method of repository to get the Object of Member class and return it
 here in the controller. Whereever in your application method you need the information kept in the session pass it in the argument to the handler. You can find more details how this information can be verified at every method call at http://faisalbhagat.blogspot.com/2014/09/session-management-with-spring-mvc.html

Comment: This example helped me ..
I was wondering how to declare and use `HttpSession` and peace code enlighten me, thank you ...