# Using session in spring mvc 3

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

I have a problem that using session in spring mvc3. I don't know how to use it. When I click on to the button Submit.. It doesn't work... I just a newbie in spring mvc...
This is my sample code:

LoginController:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"account"})
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
private CatalogService catalogSerivce;
@Autowired
private AccountService accountSerivce;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public String list(Model model) {
    List<Catalog> listCatalog = catalogSerivce.getListCatalog();
    model.addAttribute("catalogs", listCatalog);
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "tbusername") String username,
        @RequestParam(value = "tbpassword") String password,
        @ModelAttribute(value = "account") Account account) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    account = accountSerivce.authenticate(username, password);
    modelAndView.addObject("account", account);
    return new ModelAndView("index");
}
}
```

IndexController

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"account"})
public class IndexController {

@Autowired
private CatalogService catalogSerivce;

@Autowired
private ProductService productService;

@RequestMapping(value = {"/index", ""})
public String list(Model model){
    List<Catalog> listCatalog = catalogSerivce.getListCatalog();
    List<Product> listProduct = productService.searchProductByCatalog("", "");
    model.addAttribute("catalogs", listCatalog);
    model.addAttribute("products", listProduct);
    return "index";
}
}
```

login.jsp

```
<form action='login' method='post'>
<label>Username</label> <input type='text' class='field'
    name='tbusername' /> <label>Password</label> <input
    type='password' class='field' name='tbpassword' />
<input type='submit' class='search-submit' name='login'
    value='Login' />
<p>
    <a href='register' class='bul'>Don't have an account</a><br />
</form>
```

Comment: what is not working here?

Comment: I dont know when I click on button login, It doesnt work... It doesnt receive a session in index

Comment: I try to debug but It doesnt jump into the method login...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145526/httpsession-management-in-springmvc) will give you an idea about when to use `@SessionAttributes`. Below is an excerpt copied from [@SessionAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html) doc:

> NOTE: Session attributes as indicated using this annotation correspond
>   to a specific handler's model attributes, getting transparently stored
>   in a conversational session. Those attributes will be removed once the
>   handler indicates completion of its conversational session. Therefore,
>   use this facility for such conversational attributes which are
>   supposed to be stored in the session temporarily during the course of
>   a specific handler's conversation.
>
> For permanent session attributes, e.g. a user authentication object,
>   use the traditional session.setAttribute method instead.

So to make use of permanent session attributes, change your controller methods to this:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "tbusername") String username,
        @RequestParam(value = "tbpassword") String password,
        @ModelAttribute(value = "account") Account account,
        HttpSession session) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    account = accountSerivce.authenticate(username, password);
    //modelAndView.addObject("account", account);
    session.setAttribute("account", account);
    return new ModelAndView("index");
}
}
```